# How to wrapAll - ol element to ahref element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to wrap the following code in a div with a jQuery wrap:

```
<ol class="pagination-links">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ol>

<a class="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

Using the wrap function, I dont know how to call these elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('ol').each(function(i, e) {
            $(e).nextUntil('.next').wrapAll('<div>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a multiple selector -

```
$("ol.pagination-links,a.prev,a.next").wrapAll('<div>');
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jEkVC/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('ol.pagination-links, a.prev, a.next').wrapAll('<div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".pagination-links, a.prev, a.next").wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

Be aware though, because your are selecting by classes, if you have multiple instances of these elements on one page they will all be wrapped in 1 div, as opposed to each group of `ol` and 2x `a` elements per `div`

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mGm8L/)